# Positioning a button absolute x,y

Tags: java, libgdx

I've been working on some app's using libgdx & I can't figure out how to position a button via coords.

```
public void create() {
    batch = game.getSpriteBatch();
    background = new Texture("data/textures/menuScreen_small.png");

    bubbleArray = new Array<Bubble>();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        bubbleArray.add(new Bubble(MathUtils.random(0,
                Gdx.graphics.getWidth()), MathUtils.random(0,
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight())));
    }

    table = new Table();
    stage.addActor(table);
    table.setSize(1280, 720);
    table.setPosition(0, 0);
    //table.left().top();
    // table.debug();
    //table.row().minHeight(55).maxHeight(55);
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/ui/uiskin.json"));

    /*
     * HomeScreen [Button 1]
     */
    final TextButton camButton = new TextButton("Camera", skin);
    //Add button
    table.add(camButton);//.left().expandX().fillX();
    camButton.setPosition(0, 0);
    //Button Height
    //table.row().minHeight(55).maxHeight(55);
    //Button Width
    //table.row().minWidth(55).maxWidth(55);
```

In the code above I am trying to position my textButton "camButton" at 0,0 on the screen.

when I start the program it's in the very center of the screen.

If anyone has some guides or tips let me know, I need to learn this stuff.

a small 'fix'

Not exactly a fix; but by removing the table in general solved this problem. By doing this I'm adding it to the stage instead of stage > table > button. Any comments to that?

Comment: If you change the position will the button move? Or is it stuck in the center of the screen?

Comment: stuck in the center of the screen.

Comment: I haven't used Java in a little while, but could making camButton `final` be causing it?

Comment: hmm. It didn't change anything visually. I'll keep looking & playing with it until I notice something.

Comment: Added a comment to the main thread about a 'fix'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to be able to fix buttons to absolute positions like 0,0 there is no need to add the items to a table, just add you button to the stage

```
    TextButton button = new TextButton("Floating Button", skin);
    button.setPosition(10,  10);
    stage.addActor(button);
```

*Edit*
If you still want the controlled positioning that the table provides check out the guide for the table layout it has many good examples [Table Layout](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout)

If you want to position the table

```
table.left().bottom();
```

To position items inside a table

```
table.add(button).expand().bottom().right();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had your problem. My requirement for the whole screen or part of the screen was. I solved my problem using `WidgetGroup` layout.

```
actor.setPosition(100,200);
yourWidgetGroup.addActor(actor);
```